# Spring MVC seperate assets from applications war file

Tags: java, spring, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I am writing a simple web application called "webdemo" using java spring and jsp on tomcat apache server. My goal is separate the assets (jsp,images,css,js) from projects war file and store them on tomcat's classpath which I set it to tomact's "common" folder.

webdemo-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>


    <import resource="externalizationContext.xml"/> 

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.mckesson.voucher"/>

    <mvc:resources mapping="/images/**" location="classpath:application-assets/webdemo/images/" />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/scripts/**" location="classpath:application-assets/webdemo/scripts/" />

    <bean id="couponBean" class="com.mckesson.voucher.model.CouponBean" scope="session">
        <aop:scoped-proxy />
    </bean>



    <util:properties id="voucherProperties"
        location="classpath:application-config/webdemo/externalization/webdemo.properties" />
    <util:properties id="voucherEnvProperties"
        location="classpath:application-config/webdemo/logging/loggingTags.properties" />
    <util:properties id="voucherDBEnvProperties"
        location="classpath:application-config/datasource/dataSource.properties" />


<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="classpath:application-assets/webdemo/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>


</beans>
```

web.xml

```
   <!-- General description of your web application -->
      <display-name>McKesson webdemo</display-name>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/dbContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>webdemo</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>      
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>webdemo</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/home.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>  
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>webdemo</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

      <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>home.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>


      <!-- Define the default session timeout for your application,
            in minutes.  From a servlet or JSP page, you can modify
            the timeout for a particular session dynamically by using
            HttpSession.getMaxInactiveInterval(). -->
      <session-config>
            <session-timeout>30</session-timeout><!-- 30 minutes -->
      </session-config>
</web-app>
```

We have close to 300 web projects hosted on tomcat and end goal is place all the assets in single place respective to each web project under tomcat's common folder.

Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually a good idea but you are kind of going about it wrong.  One thing you need to understand is that you don't want to separate the jsp.  Keep that in Spring.  You want to separate js, css, and images because those are static content.  The common way to do that in an enterprise environment is to have a webserver, like Apache, in front of you Tomcat server.  You put the static content on the Apache server and configure that server to deliver the static content to the browser, while the calls for dynamic content are sent on to the Tomcat and relayed through the Apache server.  This reduces the load on the Tomcat server.  You might be able to do this all on one server but I haven't tried that.